# How can I use Apache Camel to transform a SOAP XML into a REST JSON request and return a response in reverse order

Tags: rest, soap, apache-camel

I want to have a SOAP XML request transformed into a matching REST POST request that will be sent to a server, processed, and then returned as a SOAP XML response.

Send SOAP XML Request -> Create REST Request -> Process Rest Request and return Rest Response -> Create and return SOAP XML response

I have set up two running applications, a camel application that will receive a SOAP XML request and send a REST POST request to an application that will return a REST response.  I am attempting to have the camel application receive the REST response and convert it into a SOAP response that will be returned to the originator of the original SOAP request.

The following is the camel-config.xml I used:

```
    <bean id="ProcessChange" class="com.acompany.camel.processor.ProcessChange"/>

  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="HTTP_EndPoint" 
                  address="/OptionalServicesService" 
      wsdlURL="classpath:optionalservices_v22_0/OptionalServicesContract.wsdl" 
      serviceClass="com.acompany.ism.optionalservices_v22_0.OptionalServicesPort"
      endpointName="tns:OptionalServicesPort"
      serviceName="tns:OptionalServicesService" 
      xmlns:tns="http://www.acompany.com/ism/optionalservices_v22_0">
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

  <cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address="http://localhost:9090/TicketRelatedSvc"
    serviceClass="com.acompany.mce.dto.response.RESBody"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" />

    <dataFormats>
        <json id="jaxreq" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.acompany.mce.dto.request.REQBody"/>
        <json id="jaxres" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.company.mce.dto.response.RESBody"/>
    </dataFormats>


    <route id="OptionalServices">
      <from uri="cxf:bean:HTTP_EndPoint"/> 
      <transform id="TransformInput"><simple>${in.body[0]}</simple></transform>
      <doTry>
        <pipeline id="HTTPPipeline" xmlns:doc6="http://www.acompany.com/ism/optionalservices_v22_0">
            <choice id="ChoiceOfVersions">    
                <when> 
                    <simple>${in.header.operationName} == 'OptionalServices'</simple>  
                    <marshal><custom ref="jaxreq"/></marshal>
                    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                        <constant>POST</constant>
                    </setHeader>
                    <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" id="header_contentType">
                        <constant>application/json</constant>
                    </setHeader>
                    <inOut uri="cxfrs://bean://rsClient"/>
                    <unmarshal ref="jaxres"/>
                </when>     
          (EXCEPTION HANDLING IS HERE)
    </route>
```

I am getting the following error:

> org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline - Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[ID-DFPC0N2-1570808508753-0-4] Exception: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DFPC0N2-1570808508753-0-4]

Comment: I wonder if what I want to do is simply not possible at this time with Camel.  All the examples use it as a Consumer and not a Producer which is what I want to do.  I will simply use some HTTP client code I have and do this the old fashion way outside of camel.

Comment: I finally found out what was going wrong with this.  I was using the latest version I could find of camel-core and camel-cxf in my pom.xml file (3.3.3).  When I changed my pom to support an older version (3.2.6), I was able to get everything to work.